# Heroku and Gemfile management

Tags: postgresql, heroku, ruby-on-rails-3.2, gemfile

I am having issues getting an app live on heroku. the error message I am receiving is:

> "Installing pg (0.14.0) with native extensions
>   /Users/blanecordes/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/installer.rb:483:in
>   `rescue in block in build_extensions': ERROR: Failed to build gem
>   native extension. (Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError)
>
> /Users/blanecordes/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p0/bin/ruby extconf.rb
>   --with-pg-config=/users/blanecordes/postgresql/bin/pg_config Using config values from /users/blanecordes/postgresql/bin/pg_config sh:
>   /users/blanecordes/postgresql/bin/pg_config: No such file or directory
>   sh: /users/blanecordes/postgresql/bin/pg_config: No such file or
>   directory checking for libpq-fe.h... *** extconf.rb failed *** Could
>   not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
>   libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details. 
>   You may need configuration options."

My gemfile is:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.2.3'

# Bundle edge Rails instead:
# gem 'rails', :git => 'git://github.com/rails/rails.git'

gem 'sqlite3'
gem 'pg'
gem 'nokogiri'
gem 'pry'

group :test, :development do
 gem 'sqlite3'
 gem "rspec-rails", "~> 2.0"
 end

# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.
group :assets do
 gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
 gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'

# See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer', :platform => :ruby

  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
end

gem 'jquery-rails'

# To use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '~> 3.0.0'

# To use Jbuilder templates for JSON
# gem 'jbuilder'

# Use unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Deploy with Capistrano
# gem 'capistrano'

# To use debugger
# gem 'ruby-debug19', :require => 'ruby-debug'
```

Comment: Try installing the Heroku Postgres add-on first: https://addons.heroku.com/heroku-postgresql

Answer (score 1):

You have `sqlite3` and `pg` in your gemfile.  They are incompatible because they do the same thing.  The best thing to do is [install postgresql](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/local-postgresql) on your local computer if you plan on staying with heroku.  Then remove `sqlite3` from your gemfile (it's in two places).

If you want to stick with sqlite3 on your local machine, wrap `pg` in a production block and only have `sqlite3` in the test, development block.

```
# gem 'sqlite3'
# gem 'pg'

group :production do
  gem 'pg'
end


group :test, :development do
  gem 'sqlite3'
  gem "rspec-rails", "~> 2.0"
end
```